# Javascript issues?

Tags: javascript

So here is what I have so far. I am trying to create a button that calculates percentages of test scores then displays onto the page when you press a button. Bear in mind i'm a VERY new programmer with less than 3 weeks experience and I could really use the help.

```
    var sam = 9;
    var sally = 8;
    var donald = 4;

function go(){
    function percentage();
    alert("Sam's score on the test is " + samp + "%\nSally's score on the test is " 
    + sallyp + "%\nDonald's score on the test is " + donaldp + "%")
}   

function percentage(){
    var samp = sam / 10 * 100;
    var sallyp = sally / 10 * 100;
    var donaldp = donald / 10 * 100;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We'd like to help, but your title nor your question contain any actual problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To invoke the percentage function, remove the function keyword.  The next issue is that samp, sallyp, and donaldp are scoped to the function percentage, so they're not accessible in the go function.  You should make percentage take an argument

```
function percentage (score) {
  return score / 10 * 100;
};
```

Then, in go:

```
function go () {
  console.log("Sam: " + percentage(sam) + ", Sally: " + percentage(sally) +
              ", Donald: " + percentage(donald));
};
```

Comment: So how would I go about displaying this without a button for future reference? Say I just wanted the scores to be displayed, but without having to hit a button?

Comment: The console.log function prints to the web console, which is common for developers to have debug information without necessarily showing users.  In Firefox, for instance, you can go to Tools > Web Developer > Browser Console.

If you want it to be displayed in page, you could use alert, but it's better to avoid alert.  I'll usually write a log function:

    function log (str) {
        var  p = document.createElement('p');
        p.textContent = str;
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    };

This should be done after DOMContentLoaded otherwise document.body wont be defined.

Comment: Also, here are some recommended reading:

1. http://mozilla-ntu.github.io/slides/site/slides/day1-section4-javascript.html#/

2. JavaScript: The Definitive Guide (David Flanigan)

3. JavaScript: The Good Parts (Douglass Crockford)

4. http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/

5. Secrets of a JavaScript Ninja (John Resig)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your script as:

```
<script>   /*writing <script type="text/javascript"> is not mandatory 
           as by default it will take javascript as type
           Semicolon is not mandatory in JS, but it's good practice to use it 
           */

    var sam = 9;
    var sally = 8;
    var donald = 4;

    function go(){            
    //there are different ways to print on page (alert, document.write, etc...)

    alert("Sam's score: " + percentage(samp) + "Sally's score: " 
    + percentage(sally) + "Donald's score: " + percentage(donald));
    }        

    function percentage(calc){
    return score / 10 * 100;
    }
</script>
```

Other ways to print may include:

--By getting element ID:
  Suppose you have a HTML element as 
                                  or

in your script, you can use:

```
var el_info = document.getElementById("abc");  // to get the element information
```

Then, you can use:

```
el_info.innerHTML = "Sam's score: " + percentage(samp) + "Sally's score: " 
                  + percentage(sally) + "Donald's score: " + percentage(donald);
```

or, you can directly use:

```
document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = "Sam's score: " +percentage(samp)+ 
 "Sally's score: "+ percentage(sally) + "Donald's score: " + percentage(donald));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables scope is not proper.....
You have two ways to declare them. First  make them global so you can access them in both functions.

Another way is to declare them inside the Go function.

According to me you should declare them into GO function.

Note : as you are working on javasceipt .you can debug your code from Console in browser when you inspect element.